# Regex to identify a character preceded or followed by a number

Tags: regex, perl

I have text that occasionally substitutes an `l` or `I` for a `1` (it's from OCR). I want to convert these to a `1` when they are part of a number, but leave them alone if they stand alone. By "part of a number" I mean adjacent to another digit or `l` or `I`. So I want to change `1I3` to `113` but leave `1 I 3` alone.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
$var =~ s/[lI](?=[lI\d])/1/g;
$var =~ s/(?<=[lI\d])[lI]/1/g;
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this in one step? In other words, what regex will match `[Il]` that is *either* preceded by `[lI\d]` *or* followed by `[lI\d]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [alternation metacharacter](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Metacharacters) `|`:

```
$var =~ s/(?<=[lI\d])[lI]|[lI](?=[lI\d])/1/g;
```

Poor Kim Jong 11, though.

Comment: Aha, thanks. Luckily for the *Dear Leader*, he doesn't appear in my data. Or other names, thankfully.

Answer (score 5):

Do you expect `llla` to be converted to `111a`? Cause your regexp does that conversion also. The problem that you are trying to solve is context-free in nature (you can embed a number adjacent or in between a stream of `[Il]`'s and only then will you convert them to `1`). I would write a loop if I were you. Correct me if I missed something.